# Remote desktop - control which monitor the connection bar shows on

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I have multiple monitors and when I remote desktop in full screen mode, there's a bar up top which lists the hostname along with minimize, restore, quit, and pin icons.  Is there some way to control which monitor this lives on?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. That dialog will always appear on the same monitor as the one hosting the remote desktop session. As you know you can get it to go away and hide but it will always reappear on the same monitor as the session once you hover your mouse over it.  Not much you can do other than using another remote desktop program.

Comment: It seems like sometimes I've seen it appear on different monitors during different sessions.  I tried relaunching remote desktop but from a different monitor and I can't seem to get it to change though.  Am I maybe misremembering? I'm quite confident it's been on different monitors.

Comment: You could try a different program always of course. I have never seen anyone ever do that.